# How can I get this output with python? Is Pandas helpful?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe  contain this records:

```
ID    Date        price    type 
1    21/09/2020   100      A
2    23/09/2020   200      A
1    25/09/2020   100      B
3    26/09/2020   500      A
2    27/09/2020   40       B
```

I want to create a new excel file that give an overview of type transactions of users as follow :

```
ID-A   Date-A    price-A  type-A  ID-B      Date-B     price-B  type-B    
1     21/09/2020   100     A       1     25/09/2020     100       B
2     23/09/2020   40      A       2     27/09/2020     40        B
2'    23/09/2020   160     A                
3     26/09/2020   500     A
```

for every id, I check the price-B :

- if `price-A == price-B`, I copy next
- if `price-A > price-B`, I split row A in two rows and I subtract price-B

I don't know how to implement it in python. Is pandas will be helpful?
Especially I should  insert row in the output in specific columns.

Comment: i dont know pandas too much, I imagine you could use it. Since you're wanting to use excel files also have a look at following packages (you can pip install them) xlsxwriter, openpyxl or pylightxl

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I see you want to split a DataFrame into separate DataFrames  by field 'type' and put next to each other using different columns.

To do this I propose to first 'group by' the type field and iterate over the group.
With each iteration you get back a tuple of value of 'group by' field ( A, B..) and related part od DataFrame
You can change column names and concat list into DataFrame.

Length of DataFrame is not balanced and will be filled with NaN.

After you have data in this format it is simple to substract values from one column to other and append new row.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas.core.algorithms import diff

data = """
ID    Date        price    type 
1    21/09/2020   100      A
2    23/09/2020   200      A
1    25/09/2020   100      B
3    26/09/2020   500      A
2    27/09/2020   40       B
"""
data = data.split("\n")
data = [d.split() for d in data if d]
data = [[s.strip() for s in d] for d in data if d]
df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns=data[0])
df['price'] = df.price.astype(float)

grp = df.groupby('type')

transformed_df_list = []

for idx, frame in grp:
    frame.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
    cols = frame.columns.tolist()
    cols_mapper = {c:f"{c}-{idx}" for c in cols}
    frame.rename(columns=cols_mapper, inplace=True)
    transformed_df_list.append(frame.copy())

result = pd.concat(transformed_df_list, axis=1)
result['prdif'] = np.where(result['price-A'] > result['price-B'], result['price-A'] - result['price-B'], 0)
difference_df = result.query('prdif>0').copy()
result['price-A'] = result['price-A']-result['prdif']


for col in difference_df.columns:
    if col[-2:] == '-B':
        difference_df[col] = np.nan
difference_df['ID-A'] = difference_df['ID-A'] + "'"
difference_df['price-A'] = difference_df['prdif']

result = result.append(difference_df).sort_values('ID-A')
result.drop(columns='prdif', inplace=True)
print(result)
```